Testing hook-up wires for inductance
Say a hypothetical question. A seller I'm going to has dubious merchandise & their hook-up wires, in particular, are NOT made out of typical high purity copper, like ordinary hook-up wires. One characteristic of their non-high-purity-copper hook-up wires is that it has higher inductance that causes significant voltage drop when powering mains AC appliances.
Say, if I were to use said hook-up wire as power cord from a 120V outlet to an electric fan, the voltage across the motor is only around 105V & the voltage across \$V_{wire}\$ is 15V.
So how do I calculate that a hook-up wire has too much inductance for an allowable \$V_{wire}\$? My analog electronics is very, very lacking, but I reckon it's something like this?
$$ 
\begin{align}
V_{wire} &< 2 \pi f L_{wire} I_{max} \\
\implies L_{wire} &>\frac{V_{wire}}{2 \pi f I_{max}}
\end{align}
$$
So I'll bring out my LC meter to measure if the inductance is indeed over this limit.
Or maybe I can simply measure the voltage across the hook-up wire? I would need a dummy resistive load & I suppose I can figure this with this formula.
$$\begin{align}
V_{wire} &< \frac{V_{main} * 2 \pi f L_{wire}}{2 \pi f L_{wire} + R_{dummy}} \\
 \implies R_{dummy} &< 2 \pi f L_{wire} (\frac{V_{main}}{V_{wire}} - 1)
\end{align}
$$

where \$I_{max} = \ 15A\$ (North American)

Am I mistaken in my method of troubleshooting this dubious product?

What do they do to this wire to change it's inductance in such a significant way as to make it significantly different from a regular copper wire? Hypothetically.

I would think it was way more likely that they just made the wire with much less copper (this is already commonly done), and it would also cause a voltage drop across the wire but not because of inductance but resistance

If you suspect a wire is not "up to standard", then your method of testing by measuring voltage drop seems quite reasonable.  However, determining whether any excess voltage drop should be attributed to either inductance or resistance is a bit more difficult, since the measurement depends on both.
You could use a DC power supply to measure voltage drop, which will provide an accurate measure of the cable resistance, since inductance does not affect DC measurements.  Using the measurement with an AC voltage source, you could then do some simple math to calculate the inductance.  However, at 50/60Hz, the resistance will tend to dominate, so it may be quite difficult to accurately measure inductance with this method.  That is where an accurate LC meter will be much better.
However, it is important to note that inductance is determined by the geometry of a circuit rather than by the material of the conductor.

yep, the question whether you form a coil with the cabling vs whether you lay it out in as straight as possible will dominate, at 50 Hz, by far.


One characteristic of their non-high-purity-copper hook-up wires is that it has higher inductance that causes significant voltage drop when powering mains AC appliances.

Inductance is determined by the shape of the conductor, not by its material.
The dubious wires are made likely from tin- or copper-coated aluminum, and they have higher resistance that causes significant voltage drop when conducting either AC or DC.
These wires are unusable since connecting to an aluminum wire requires special precautions, i.e. just a basic solder joint does not do the trick at all. The tin- or copper- plating is so thin that it dissolves rather quickly in the molten solder, and you're left with soldering to aluminum under temporarily oxygen-free conditions. It will have the appearance of working at first. And then it will progressively fail due to various reasons.
So, you don't need to worry about the resistance at all. You can't use those wires.

So how do I calculate that a hook-up wire has too much inductance for an allowable Vwire?

You'll be calculating resistance, so Ohm's law is all you need.
You'll have to first determine what the Vwire is, and that is determined from the thermal power the wire is allowed to dissipate. I.e. Pwire = Vwire * Iwire, and Pwire is limited by the allowed temperature rise of the wire. The temperature rise is chosen to be say 30C, and then the maximum Pwire depends on the thermal conductivity of the wire's insulator, the length of the wire, and its diameter - i.e. how well it can dissipate the heat.
